# Creating a Dashboard with a Livestream option

Tags: node.js, postgresql

As the title says I am trying to am creating a Dashboard.

The Dashboard should include an option to view Data inserted in a Database, live or at least "live" with minimal delay.

I was thinking about 2 approaches:

1. When the option is used the Back-End creates a Trigger in the Database(its only certain Data so i would have to change the Trigger according to the Data). Said trigger should then send the new Data via http to the Back-End. 
   What i see as a problem is that the delay of sending the Data and possible errors could block the whole database.

1.1. Same as 1. but the trigger puts the new Data in a seperate Table where i can then query and delete the Data.

2. Just query for the newest data every 1-5 sec. or so. This just seems extremly bad and avoidable.

Which of those is the best way to do this? Am i missing something? How is this usually done?

The Database is a pgsql Database,Back and Front-end are in NodeJs.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue you are having? Your question is largely opinion based, which is not suitable for Stack Overflow.  Please look around on Stack Exchange for a better place to post this. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My question is how to do this, since I dont know how to. I just listed my examples as ways i thought that might be usefull.

Comment: You're not asking for help with a specific issue you are having.  You are asking an extremely broad and opinionated question.  You are not explaining the exact issue you are having.  You are essentially asking how to structure and write a dashboard... have you checked https://google.com ? What have you done? Have you tested your theories? Please ask a specific question about the exact issue you are having. Please revisit the links I supplied above.